# Strange symbols in a file when opened up in Notepad++

Tags: file, encoding, symbols

I am trying to edit a file. The file type is simply "*file*".
I have extensions turned on and there is none for these. 
When I open it up in Notepad++ it shows the content in the following manner:
**ÞË42€Ãº´ü}}ÀÜ‚«Ÿ_‘‚BË¯D‡¦÷\þöÂéÄýñÖÜ'!ùDF®2×M‰Ò`;nõ®¤y ÓUßZÕèÇ¹…‡Óß;e©ÝÛÑ¦—Priï[ç¸ó_›DY©×eJ;HÕÈ^0ðµQ_üü™•**

My guess was that this is binary, but I am not sure. The encoding is ANSI. I was told that Notepad++ would show a binary file as binary. I am curious as to what type of information this is, as I intend to edit it.

I haven't gotten anywhere with research because I don't know what to search; I have seen this before and just assumed it was binary, but I am not so sure anymore.

My intent is to convert it into a file that I can understand and edit. My reason is that one of two files(both with the same file type and strange contents) must contain a progress record for a math education program I am using. I did not know I needed to save the progress, as I had thought you could manually set lessons to completed - I was wrong, and now have lost several months of finished lessons.

Any help is appreciated.
**Update:** Notepad, the default program on Windows for opening text files, does not open it. I tried several times and it froze.
 **Update:** I now have a hex viewer/editor. Obviously this file is just a bunch of numbers and not in a readable language(Which is now obvious to me - this would simply be where the program stores info, not where it uses it). Since there aren't any comments at all, I believe my efforts are in vain as I do not know what corresponds to what in the program. Am I right in the assumption that this isn't a file of commands but rather a 'dump' for info the computer wants to save? If so I would have to de-compile the program in order to see how this info is stored and accessed in order to change the grades I have lost?
*Thanks to all those who responded!*

Comment: You wouldn't normally edit a binary file in Notepad++.  What kind of file is it, and what are you trying to change in it?

Comment: Do you know if the file can actually be read by a human? If it's just bytestrings, it will only make sense in a certain context. If it should be human readable, just try other encodings.

Comment: @JRQ Well that is my question. The file type that windows reports is "file". It has no file extension that I can see, and yes I have my file extensions visible.

Comment: @Carcigenicate No, I am not sure. I will edit the post to explain my more specific reasons.

Comment: @CAA14 It's most likely meant to be opened by a specific program, a d the extension was dropped for some reason. There may be programs that exist that can look at the file and try to figure out what the extension should be.

Comment: @CAA14 - Most operating systems, Windows included do not make efforts to identify file types based on content.  Windows still only uses the file extension to display the type in Explorer.  For instance, if you rename an MP3 file from "mysong.mp3" to "mysong.jpg", Windows will display the filetype as "JPG".

Comment: Continued,,,,Your first problem is to identify the filetype, which can usually be done by looking at the first 16 or so bytes in the file. This is best done with a hex viewer, and then you can try searching Google to get a match on the first 4 / 8 / 16 bytes.  There may be other clues in the file in the form of readable ASCII strings.

Comment: What is the name of the Math education program?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay, I will try to find a program that can read it.

Comment: @JRQ <br> Oh, I see. Well I had no idea... That's pretty strange in my opinion.<br> Excuse me, but though I am pretty learned in programming itself, I lack experience and a good solid education in computers and networks. Therefore I must ask: What do you mean by 'byte'? I know what that is, it is a measure of information that a computer holds, but I have no idea **how** to measure any data. I will look for a hex viewer. The math program is called "Teaching Textbooks".

Comment: @CAA14 Sometimes applications will use a standard method of saving progress, or program state.  Other times they will use a custom scheme, or even just a memory dump.  The benefit of using a hex viewer is that you might be able to determine if the file format was say SQLite, which will always have the following byte sequence at the front of the file: "53 51 4c 69 74 65 20 66 6f 72 6d 61 74 20 33 00", but this is not the case for your example.  It's not unusual to not be able to de-code a "saved" file.

Comment: @JRQ Thanks, and I now have a hex viewer. I am going to attempt to de-compile it and see if I can figure it out that way. Thanks for all the help.